# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Why is this error coming for Jenkins Shared Pipeline library?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, pipeline

I have a shared pipeline library [code](https://github.com/arghyadeep-k/springboot-shared-library.git). The library is loaded implicitly in my Jenkins and I'm calling one of the methods using the following code in my Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
    CheckOut {}
}
```

I've also tried using `CheckOut.call()` & `CheckOut.call([:],{})` but to no avail.
Keep getting the following error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: CheckOut.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@668faf1f]
Possible solutions: call(), wait(), any(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

P.S. - The error is not specific to one function and is happening for all the other functions of the library as well.

Comment: Did you try `CheckOut()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. While configuring the shared library repo in Jenkins Global Configuration, fill in the link without .git in the end.

For example, use https://github.com/arghyadeep-k/jenkins-shared-library and not https://github.com/arghyadeep-k/jenkins-shared-library.git.

And, then invoke the functions in your Jenkinsfile as

```
node{
    checkOut.call()
}
```